# Promisify a recursive function in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, recursion, promise, bluebird

I'm using [bluebird](https://www.npmjs.org/package/bluebird) for the control flow in my application, I'm trying to implement **promisify** to extend my recursive function into a promise, but it seems like the "then" method never got executed

I'm doing a mapping from one JSON object to another, the find function looks recursively into the JSON properties and returns the property based on an specific condition.

```
var promise = require("bluebird");
var mapToModel = function(res){
  // res is a json structure
  var processes = res.definitions.process;
  var diagrams = res.definitions.BPMNDiagram; 
  var documents = [];
  for(var prop in processes) {
    if(processes.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      var propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(processes[prop]);
      for(var property in processes[prop]){
        var mapping ={};
        if(property==="$"){
          //do something with the process
        }else{
        //shapes
          mapping.hash = hash.hashCode(new Date().toString());
          mapping.type = property;
          mapping.value = processes[prop][property];
            var bpmnItem = findPromise(processes[prop][property], function(x) {return x.$.id;}).then(function(value){
              //I'm not reaching this point
              var bpmnId = value.$.id;
              console.log(value);
              if(bpmnId!=undefined){
                console.log("return:"+ bpmnId);
              }  
          });

          documents.push(mapping);
        }
      }
    }
     return documents;
  }
}

var findPromise = promise.promisify(find);
function find(items,f) {
    for(var key in items) { 
        var elem = items[key]; 
        if (f(elem)) { return elem;}
        if(typeof elem === "object") { 
            find(elem,f); // call recursively
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bluebird promisify method works on the accepted callback convention for NodeJS - nodebacks.

Nodebacks are in the specific format of `someOp(function(err,result){` that is - the first argument is always an error.

In fact, your `find` method is not even asynchronous, so there is no reason to promisify it to begin with. You can simply call it as it is.

**Generally, you should not promisify synchronous functions**, you just call them normally. In fact, you don't seem to have any asynchronous operation in your code - so you should not be using promises at all in it.

You can simply do:

```
mapping.value = processes[prop][property];
var value = find(processes[prop][property], function(x) {return x.$.id;});
var bpmnId = value.$.id;
console.log(value);
if(bpmnId!=undefined){
    console.log("return:"+ bpmnId);
}
```

Remember, Promises are an abstraction over an eventual result. You keep doing everything synchronous just like you did before.

Comment: that was my first option just setting the value using the function, that worked fine for small "find" condions but when I tried with more complex operations the I noticed in the flow control didn't wait for  execution of the function, that's the reason I decided to try  to implement promises

Comment: @Pedro didn't wait for the execution of the function? JavaScript (unless you explicitly ask for it) has no notion of preemptive multitasking, simply put - all code runs to completion. If your code did not run to completion - that means you did something asynchronous. If you did - please create a self contained example of _that_ (preferably in a new question). Otherwise, your code might have thrown an exception. Generally, you should not promisify APIs that don't use callbacks anyway.

Comment: thanks for the help, I have created another question with my the other scenario I described earlier on, any help would be totally appreciated  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23613036/null-value-when-calling-a-recursive-function-in-node-js