# Null value when calling a recursive function in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, recursion

I have this scenario I'm trying to map one JSON definition to another, I have a recursive function named **find** which works perfectly when I do simple operations but when I send complex conditions I always get a **undefined** value over the assigment.

```
  var mapToModel = function(res){
  var processes = res.definitions.process;
  var diagrams = res.definitions.BPMNDiagram; 
  var documents = [];
  for(var prop in processes) {
    if(processes.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      var propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(processes[prop]);
      for(var property in processes[prop]){
        var mapping ={};
        if(property==="$"){
          //do something with the process
        }else{
        //shapes
          console.log("\n");
          mapping.id = new mongo.ObjectID();
          mapping.hash = hash.hashCode(new Date().toString());
          mapping.type = property;
          mapping.value = processes[prop][property];
          var bpmnItem = find(processes[prop][property], function(x) {return x;});
          var bpmnId = bpmnItem.$.id;
          console.log("bpmnId: "+bpmnId);
            if(bpmnId!=undefined){
              var returnVal =  find(diagrams,function(x){
                if(x.bpmnElement===bpmnId){
                  console.log("element found: " + JSON.stringify(x,null,4));
                  return x;
                }
              });
              console.log("returned value: "+returnVal);
          }
          documents.push(mapping);
        }
      }
    }
     return documents;
  }
}



function find(items,f) {
    for(var key in items) { 
        var elem = items[key]; 
        if (f(elem)) { console.log(JSON.stringify(elem,null,4)); return elem;}
        if(typeof elem === "object") { 
            find(elem,f); // call recursively
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

the console output is the following:

```
bpmnId: StartEvent_1
element found: {
    "id": "BPMNShape_1",
    "bpmnElement": "StartEvent_1"
}
returned value: undefined


bpmnId: SequenceFlow_9
element found: {
    "id": "BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_10",
    "bpmnElement": "SequenceFlow_9",
    "sourceElement": "BPMNShape_1",
    "targetElement": "BPMNShape_Task_3"
}
returned value: undefined
```

etc, etc...

an exmaple of the input data

```
"BPMNDiagram": [
            {
                "$": {
                    "id": "BPMNDiagram_1",
                    "name": "procurement subprocess"
                },
                "BPMNPlane": [
                    {
                        "$": {
                            "id": "BPMNPlane_1",
                            "bpmnElement": "process"
                        },
                        "BPMNShape": [
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "id": "BPMNShape_1",
                                    "bpmnElement": "StartEvent_1"
                                },
                                "Bounds": [
                                    {
                                        "$": {
                                            "height": "36.0",
                                            "width": "36.0",
                                            "x": "20.0",
                                            "y": "182.0"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "id": "BPMNShape_Task_3",
                                    "bpmnElement": "Task_2"
                                },
                                "Bounds": [
                                    {
                                        "$": {
                                            "height": "50.0",
                                            "width": "110.0",
                                            "x": "100.0",
                                            "y": "175.0"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "$": {
                                    "id": "BPMNShape_ExclusiveGateway_2",
                                    "bpmnElement": "ExclusiveGateway_2",
                                    "isMarkerVisible": "true"
                                },
                                "Bounds": [
                                    {
                                        "$": {
                                            "height": "50.0",
                                            "width": "50.0",
                                            "x": "250.0",
                                            "y": "175.0"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                        }// it continues
```

Comment: *What* complex things do you send? Example input, please! Also, *where* are you getting `null` assignments?

Comment: small note: use 'found' instead of 'finded'

Comment: Your condition should better be `function(x){ return x.bpmnElement===bpmnId; }` - returning the boolean result instead of the value that fulfills the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
var mapToModel = function(res){
  var processes = res.definitions.process;
  var diagrams = res.definitions.BPMNDiagram; 
  var documents = [];
  for(var prop in processes) {
    if(processes.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      var propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(processes[prop]);
      for(var property in processes[prop]){
        var mapping ={};
        if(property==="$"){
          //do something with the process
        }else{
        //shapes
          mapping.hash = hash.hashCode(new Date().toString());
          mapping.type = property;
          mapping.value = processes[prop][property];
          var bpmnItem = find(processes[prop][property], function(x) {return x.$.id;});
          var bpmnId = bpmnItem.$.id;//value is ok

            if(bpmnId!=undefined){
              var returnVal;
              find(diagrams,function(x){

                if( x.$ != undefined && x.$.bpmnElement != undefined ){

                  if(x.$.bpmnElement===bpmnId){
                    {returnVal =  x;}
                  }
                }
              });

              console.log("return:"+ returnVal);
          }
          documents.push(mapping);
        }
      }
    }
     return documents;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I'm just wondering why the simple assigment didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly what you are going for, but `undefined` is not the same as `null`.  In your code, you only return if `f(elem)` is truthy, so all other cases the result will be `undefined` (because you didn't return anything else).  If if your code is failing with a more complex object, then it must not be finding anything.

EDIT: 
after looking at your example data, I don't see anywhere where an `id` fields matches `bpmnElement`, so your find function will never find anything.

Comment: thanks the condition is x.bpmnElement===bpmnId the bpmnElement property is inside "$" object, the function reach the value and retuns the element in this case "x", when I do the console log in the find function inside the condition I get the object, but when I do another console log outside the function which is suposed that should return the value then I got undefined, do you think that could be an issue related to  a scope?

Comment: I have updated the console.log with the values I get